# Получение всей информации о всех взаимодействиях с мышью

Tags: c#, мышь

Нужно получить всю информацию о взаимодействиях пользователя с мышью (клик, передвижение, удержание...).

Я знаю, как получить движения мыши или нажатия клавиш по отдельности, но хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли получать всё это в куче, вроде какого-то лога?

Comment: Уточните, где вы хотите получить эту информацию в c# программе или в системе?

Answer (score 2):

Для USB-мышей в Windows лог событий можно получить с помощью механизма Event Tracing. Этот механизм позволяет собирать события от определенных источников (провайдеров) и сохранять их в файл журнала событий (.etl). Этот файл потом можно открыть с помощью стандартной оснастки просмотра событий Windows или специализированного софта типа Network Monitor, либо прочитать программно с помощью того же API.

Отслеживать передаваемые данные USB-устройств позволяют провайдеры *Microsoft-Windows-USB-USBPORT* (USB 2.0, введен в Windows 7) и *Microsoft-Windows-USB-UCX* (USB 3.0, введен в Windows 8); USB-мышь отправляет данные по протоколу HID, приблизительную структуру ее пакета можно посмотреть [здесь](http://lms.ee.hm.edu/~seck/AlleDateien/OS9HILFE/OS9-Manuals-Teil2/usb_host.pdf). Для работы с Event Tracing в .NET существует библиотека [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/).

Для запуска сеансов отслеживания требуются права администратора, но для чтения сохраненных логов они не обязательны. Запуск/остановку сеансов отслеживания можно также производить не из кода, а с помощью утилиты командной строки logman. Большой плюс способа в том, что сеанс отслеживания управляется самой системой и работает независимо от программы, т.е. можно закрыть программу и продолжать отслеживание (параметр StopOnDispose = false), пока сеанс не будет явно остановлен (программно или через logman / системный монитор). При желании можно настроить и так, чтобы отслеживание начиналось сразу при загрузке системы. Недостаток в том, что данные по движению мыши приходят не в пикселях, а в аппаратных единицах, и преобразовать их в пиксельные координаты довольно сложно.

Пример кода отслеживания HID-пакетов для клавиатуры есть [здесь](https://github.com/CyberPoint/Ruxcon2016ETW/tree/master/KeyloggerPOC). Модифицируем его, так чтобы можно было сохранять события в файл и добавим обработку мышиных пакетов, получаем что-то такое:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session;
using System.Threading;    

namespace EtwHidlogger
{
    public interface IPrint
    {
        void Print(string text);
    }

    public class KeyMap
    {
        public static string[] GetKey(int value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {                
                case 0x00: return new string[1]; // unused
                case 0x04: return new[] { "a", "A" };
                case 0x05: return new[] { "b", "B" };
                case 0x06: return new[] { "c", "C" };
                case 0x07: return new[] { "d", "D" };
                case 0x08: return new[] { "e", "E" };
                case 0x09: return new[] { "f", "F" };
                case 0x0A: return new[] { "g", "G" };
                case 0x0B: return new[] { "h", "H" };
                case 0x0C: return new[] { "i", "I" };
                case 0x0D: return new[] { "j", "J" };
                case 0x0E: return new[] { "k", "K" };
                case 0x0F: return new[] { "l", "L" };
                case 0x10: return new[] { "m", "M" };
                case 0x11: return new[] { "n", "N" };
                case 0x12: return new[] { "o", "O" };
                case 0x13: return new[] { "p", "P" };
                case 0x14: return new[] { "q", "Q" };
                case 0x15: return new[] { "r", "R" };
                case 0x16: return new[] { "s", "S" };
                case 0x17: return new[] { "t", "T" };
                case 0x18: return new[] { "u", "U" };
                case 0x19: return new[] { "v", "V" };
                case 0x1A: return new[] { "w", "W" };
                case 0x1B: return new[] { "x", "X" };
                case 0x1C: return new[] { "y", "Y" };
                case 0x1D: return new[] { "z", "Z" };
                case 0x1E: return new[] { "1", "!" };
                case 0x1F: return new[] { "2", "@" };
                case 0x20: return new[] { "3", "#" };
                case 0x21: return new[] { "4", "$" };
                case 0x22: return new[] { "5", "%" };
                case 0x23: return new[] { "6", "^" };
                case 0x24: return new[] { "7", "&" };
                case 0x25: return new[] { "8", "*" };
                case 0x26: return new[] { "9", "(" };
                case 0x27: return new[] { "0", ")" };
                case 0x28: return new[] { "[RET]" };
                case 0x29: return new[] { "[ESC]" };
                case 0x2A: return new[] { "[DEL]" };
                case 0x2B: return new[] { "[TAB]" };
                case 0x2C: return new[] { "[SPACE]" };
                case 0x2D: return new[] { "-", "_" };
                case 0x2E: return new[] { "=", "+" };
                case 0x2F: return new[] { "[", "{" };
                case 0x30: return new[] { "]", "}" };
                case 0x31: return new[] { "\\", "|" };
                case 0x32: return new[] { "#", "~" };       //non-US
                case 0x33: return new[] { ";", ":" };
                case 0x34: return new[] { "\'", "\"" };
                case 0x35: return new[] { "`", "~" };
                case 0x36: return new[] { ";", "<" };
                case 0x37: return new[] { ".", ">" };
                case 0x38: return new[] { "/", "?" };
                case 0x39: return new[] { "[CAPS]" };
                case 0x3A: return new[] { "[F1]" };
                case 0x3B: return new[] { "[F2]" };
                case 0x3C: return new[] { "[F3]" };
                case 0x3D: return new[] { "[F4]" };
                case 0x3E: return new[] { "[F5]" };
                case 0x3F: return new[] { "[F6]" };
                case 0x40: return new[] { "[F7]" };
                case 0x41: return new[] { "[F8]" };
                case 0x42: return new[] { "[F9]" };
                case 0x43: return new[] { "[F10]" };
                case 0x44: return new[] { "[F11]" };
                case 0x45: return new[] { "[F12]" };
                case 0x46: return new[] { "[PRT]" };
                case 0x47: return new[] { "[SCL]" };
                case 0x48: return new[] { "[PAU]" };
                case 0x49: return new[] { "[INS]" };
                case 0x4A: return new[] { "[HOME]" };
                case 0x4B: return new[] { "[P-UP]" };
                case 0x4C: return new[] { "[FWD]" };
                case 0x4D: return new[] { "[END]" };
                case 0x4E: return new[] { "[P-DN]" };
                case 0x4F: return new[] { "[RT]" };
                case 0x50: return new[] { "[LT]" };
                case 0x51: return new[] { "[DN]" };
                case 0x52: return new[] { "[UP]" };
                case 0x53: return new[] { "[NUM]", "[CLR]" };
                case 0x54: return new[] { "/" };
                case 0x55: return new[] { "*" };
                case 0x56: return new[] { "-" };
                case 0x57: return new[] { "+" };
                case 0x58: return new[] { "[ENTER]" };
                case 0x59: return new[] { "1", "[END]" };
                case 0x5A: return new[] { "2", "[DN]" };
                case 0x5B: return new[] { "3", "[P-DN]" };
                case 0x5C: return new[] { "4", "[LT]" };
                case 0x5D: return new[] { "5" };
                case 0x5E: return new[] { "6", "[RT]" };
                case 0x5F: return new[] { "7", "[HOME]" };
                case 0x60: return new[] { "8", "[UP]" };
                case 0x61: return new[] { "9", "[P-UP]" };
                case 0x62: return new[] { "0", "[INS]" };
                case 0x63: return new[] { ".", "[DEL]" };
                case 0x64: return new[] { "\\", "|" };      //non-US

                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }

    /*Represents a block of data transferred via USB*/
    public class UsbData
    {
        public byte usbver; //usb version (2.0 or 3.0)
        public byte[] data; //transferred bytes
        public ulong hndl; //device handle
        public DateTime time; //timestamp
        public uint vid; //Vendor ID (2.0 only)
        public uint pid; //Product ID (2.0 only)
        public uint datalen; //amount of bytes transferred

        public UsbData(DateTime inputTime, ulong inputHndl, byte[] inputData)
        {
            time = inputTime;
            data = inputData;
            hndl = inputHndl;
        }
    }

    /*A class to manage Event tracing for Windows sessions*/
    public class UsbEventSource
    {
        // Microsoft-Windows-USB-UCX (usb3.0)
        private static Guid UsbUcx = new Guid("36DA592D-E43A-4E28-AF6F-4BC57C5A11E8");
        // Microsoft-Windows-USB-USBPORT (usb2.0)
        private static Guid UsbPort = new Guid("C88A4EF5-D048-4013-9408-E04B7DB2814A");

        private static string sessionName = "UsbKeylog";
        public static TraceEventSession session;

        public static IPrint Instance; //object to display things on GUI                

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts new event tracing session
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newSessionName">Session name</param>
        /// <param name="filename">Path where to save event log file</param>
        public static void StartCapture(string newSessionName = null, string filename = "log.etl")
        {
            if (session != null) StopCapture();

            if (newSessionName != null)
                sessionName = newSessionName;

            session = new TraceEventSession(
                sessionName,
                filename);              

            session.EnableProvider(UsbUcx);
            session.EnableProvider(UsbPort);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops event tracing session
        /// </summary>
        public static void StopCapture()
        {
            if (session != null)
            {
                session.Stop();
                session.Dispose();
                session = null;
            }
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, string> _expose(object hidden)
        {
            string str = hidden.ToString();
            char[] separators = { '{', '}', ',' };
            char[] remove = { ' ', '"' };
            string[] s = str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Dictionary<string, string> item = s.ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=')[0].Trim(), x => x.Split('=')[1].Trim(remove));
            return item;
        }

        //Gets item with certain name from event data
        private static object GetItem(TraceEvent eventData, string item)
        {  
            object value = null;
            int pIndex = eventData.PayloadIndex(item);
            if (pIndex < 0)
                return value;

            try
            {
                value = eventData.PayloadValue(pIndex);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {                
            }

            return value;
        }

        //Parses usb event data
        private static UsbData GetData(TraceEvent eventData)
        {
            ulong hndl;
            object field;
            uint vid=0,pid=0;
            byte usbver = 0;

            //try to determine device handle and IDs
            field = GetItem(eventData, "fid_USBPORT_Device");
            if (field != null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> deviceInfo = _expose(field);

                if (!ulong.TryParse(deviceInfo["DeviceHandle"], out hndl) && hndl <= 0)
                    return null;

                vid = UInt32.Parse(deviceInfo["idVendor"]);
                pid = UInt32.Parse(deviceInfo["idProduct"]);
            }
            else
            {
                hndl = (ulong)GetItem(eventData, "fid_PipeHandle");
                if (hndl <= 0) return null;
            }

            //try to get event parameters
            field = GetItem(eventData, "fid_USBPORT_URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER"); //2.0
            usbver = 2;
            if (field == null)
            {
                field = GetItem(eventData, "fid_UCX_URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER"); //3.0
                usbver = 3;
            }
            Dictionary<string, string> urb = _expose(field);//transform parameter string to dictionary

            //determine transferred data length
            int xferDataSize = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(urb["fid_URB_TransferBufferLength"], out xferDataSize))
                return null;
            if ((xferDataSize > 8) && (usbver == 2)) xferDataSize = 8; //USB 2.0 sometimes gives wrong size 

            if (xferDataSize > 8) return null; //data is too large for mouse / keyboard

            byte[] data2=eventData.EventData();
            byte[] xferData = new byte[xferDataSize];
            Array.Copy(data2, eventData.EventDataLength - xferDataSize, xferData, 0, xferDataSize);

            bool HasNonZero = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < xferDataSize; i++)
                if (xferData[i] != 0) { HasNonZero = true; break; }
            if (HasNonZero == false) return null; //data is empty

            /* Construct UsbData object*/
            UsbData data = new UsbData(eventData.TimeStamp, hndl, xferData);
            data.usbver = usbver;
            data.datalen = (uint)xferDataSize;
            data.vid = vid;
            data.pid = pid;
            return data;
        }



        //Method called on new event
        public static void EventCallback(TraceEvent eventData)
        {

            if (eventData.EventDataLength <= 0)
                return;

            UsbData usbdata = null;
            string output = "";

            try
            {

                if (eventData.PayloadNames.Contains("fid_USBPORT_URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER")
                    || eventData.PayloadNames.Contains("fid_UCX_URB_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER"))
                    usbdata = GetData(eventData);

                if (usbdata == null) return;

                string idstr="";
                if (usbdata.usbver == 2)
                {
                    idstr = String.Format("VID_0x{0} PID_0x{1}", usbdata.vid.ToString("X4"), usbdata.pid.ToString("X4"));
                }

                //determine what device data comes from and actual length of data (for USB 2.0)
                bool IsMouse = false;
                uint len = usbdata.datalen;

                //(mouse data is 4 or 5 bytes, keyboard - 8 bytes)
                if (usbdata.datalen < 8) { IsMouse = true; len = usbdata.datalen; }
                else
                {
                    if (usbdata.usbver == 2 &&
                        usbdata.data[0] == 0 && usbdata.data[1] == 0 &&
                        usbdata.data[2] == 4 && usbdata.data[3] == 0) { IsMouse = true; len = 4; }
                    else if (usbdata.usbver == 2 && 
                        usbdata.data[0] == 5 && usbdata.data[1] == 0) { IsMouse = true; len = 5; }
                    else IsMouse = false;
                }

                //Print data
                if (IsMouse == false && usbdata.data[1]==0) //second byte must be zero for keyboard
                {
                    var arr = ParseKeys(usbdata.data);
                    output = String.Format("{0} {1} Keyboard ", usbdata.time, idstr);
                    if (arr != null) foreach (var s in arr) output += s + " ";
                }
                else
                {                                        
                    sbyte b;
                    output = String.Format("{0} {1} Mouse ",usbdata.time,idstr);

                    uint i_start = usbdata.datalen - len;                                        
                    uint index;
                    bool action = false;

                    for (uint i = i_start; i < usbdata.datalen; i++)
                    {
                        index = i - i_start;
                        b = (sbyte)usbdata.data[i];
                        switch (index)
                        {
                            case 0: //first byte defines pressed buttons
                                if ((usbdata.data[i] & 0x01) > 0) {output+= "Left button press ";action=true;}
                                if ((usbdata.data[i] & 0x02) > 0) {output += "Right button press ";action=true;}
                                if ((usbdata.data[i] & 0x04) > 0) {output += "Middle button press ";action=true;}
                                if ((usbdata.data[i] & 0x08) > 0) {output += "Special button press ";action=true;}
                                if ((usbdata.data[i] & 0xf0) > 0) { output += "Special button press ";action = true; }

                                break;
                            case 1: //second byte is x movement
                                if (usbdata.data[i] != 0 || usbdata.data[i + 1] != 0) { output += "move: "; action = true; }
                                if (usbdata.data[i] != 0) output += "dx=" + b.ToString() + " ";
                                break;
                            case 2: //third byte is y movement
                                if (usbdata.data[i] != 0) output += "dy=" + b.ToString() + " ";
                                break;
                            case 3: //4th byte (if present) is wheel movement
                                if (usbdata.data[i] != 0)
                                {
                                    output += "Wheel Move: Delta=" + b.ToString() + " ";
                                    action = true;
                                }
                                break;
                        }

                        /*output += b.ToString() + " ";*/
                    }
                    if (!action) output += "Button release";

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output = "Error in callback: "+ex.GetType().ToString()+" "+ex.Message;
            }

            if(output!="")Instance.Print(output);
            //datastore.Add(usbdata);
        }



        private static string[] ParseKeys(byte[] bytes)
        {
            string[] result = new string[2];
            result[0] = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", " ");

            // modifiers:
            //  CTL = 1
            //  SFT = 2
            //  ALT = 4
            byte modByte = bytes[0];
            byte noneByte = bytes[1];

            byte[] dataBytes = new byte[6];
            Array.Copy(bytes, 2, dataBytes, 0, 6);

            string[] fullKeyStroke = new string[6];

            // convert usageId -> usageName
            for (int i = 0; i < fullKeyStroke.Length; i++)
            {
                int usageId = dataBytes[i];
                string[] key = KeyMap.GetKey(usageId);

                // skip unmapped data
                if (key == null)
                    return null;

                // empty data (usageId == 0)
                if (key.SequenceEqual(new string[1]))
                {
                    fullKeyStroke[i] = "";
                    continue;
                }

                // [SFT]
                if ((modByte & 0x22) != 0)
                    fullKeyStroke[i] = key.Last();
                else
                    fullKeyStroke[i] = key.First();
            }

            string parsed = "";
            if ((modByte & 0x11) != 0)
                parsed += "[CTL] ";
            if ((modByte & 0x44) != 0)
                parsed += "[ALT] ";
            parsed += String.Join(" ", fullKeyStroke);
            result[1] = parsed.Trim();

            return result;
        }        

    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EtwHidlogger;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session;

namespace HidLogger
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IPrint
    {
        StringBuilder sb;

        public void Print(string text)
        {
            if (sb == null) sb = new StringBuilder(50000);
            if (text == null) return;
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                sb.AppendLine(text);
            }));
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UsbEventSource.Instance = this;
        }

        //запуск сеанса отслеживания
        private void bStartCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string session = tbSessionName.Text;            

            try
            {
                UsbEventSource.StartCapture(session, tbFile.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Capture sesion is started");   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tbEvents.Text = ex.ToString();
            }            
        }

        //остановка сеанса отслеживания
        private void bStopCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                UsbEventSource.StopCapture();
                MessageBox.Show("Capture sesion is stopped");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tbEvents.Text = ex.ToString();
            }  

        }

        //чтение сохраненных событий из .etl-файла
        private void bViewEvents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbEvents.Text = "";
            sb = new StringBuilder(50000);
            try
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                ETWTraceEventSource src = new ETWTraceEventSource(tbFile.Text);
                src.Dynamic.All += UsbEventSource.EventCallback;
                src.Process();

                string s;
                if 
                    (sb.Length <= 100000) s = sb.ToString();
                else 
                    s = sb.ToString().Substring(0, 99999) +
                        Environment.NewLine + "(some text trimmed)";

                tbEvents.Text = s;                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tbEvents.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, ОС не логирует активность мыши и других устройств ввода. Вы можете сами вести такой лог на уровне вашего приложения, реагируя на соответствующие события или глобально  системе, слушая соответствующие сообщения WinAPI. В последнем случае будьте готовы, что система безопасности может вполне обоснованно считать вашу программу келогером и прибить без каких либо вопросов.